# Find the eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone give me some guidance on how to obtain the eigenvalue and eigenvector for the following equation? Don't I need another equation?

$EIu_{yy}+pu=0$ where $\lambda=\frac{p}{EI}$

Comment: $\lambda$ does not appear in the equation? Also, you would need some boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2u}{{\rm d}y^2} = - \lambda u 
$$

And try solutions of the form

$$
u(y) = A e^{\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}y}
$$

Eigenvectors are $u$ and eigenvalues are $\lambda$